# For $A \subset X$, $C_n(X) \cong C_{n}(A) \oplus C_n(X,A)$ doesn't imply $H_n(X) \cong H_{n}(A) \oplus H_n(X,A)$ in general.

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra, exact-sequence

This is exercise 2.2.27 in Hatcher's [*Algebraic Topology*](http://pi.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/AT.pdf)

> The short exact sequence $0 \to C_{n}(A) \to C_{n}(X) \to C_{n}(X, A) \to 0$ always splits, but why does this not always yield splittings $H_n(X) \cong H_{n}(A) \oplus H_n(X,A)$?

My understandings are moved to the answer.

Are there better ideas? Thanks for your time and effort.

Comment: Your condition in "2" for exact sequences splitting is not correct: indeed, having an exact sequence $0 \to H_n(A) \to H_n(X)$ is exactly having $i_*$ be injective. Stare at this for a minute and things should become clear.

Comment: @user3482749 Thanks for your correction, I've fixed it.

Comment: You've somewhat missed the point. The point is that there is not, in general, an exact sequence $0 \to H_n(A) \to H_n(X) \to H_n(X,A) \to 0$. Indeed, the long exact sequence of homology shows us that such holds only when $H_{n+1}(X,A) = 0$ and $H_{n-1}(A) = 0$.

Comment: @user3482749: more precisely, there is such an exact sequence when the maps $H_{n+1}(X,A) \to H_n(A)$ and $H_n(X,A) \to H_{n-1}(A)$ are zero. Consider the case where $X = A \vee B$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some incorrect statements in the existing answer.

1) It *is* true that $C_*(X,A)$ is isomorphic, as a graded free abelian group, to the space of simplices not contained in $A$. What is not true is that this isomorphism preserves the differential; in fact, the boundary of a simplex not contained in $A$ may have faces in $A$, so this subspace of $C_*(X)$ isn't even a chain complex.

The boundary operator on $C_*(X,A)$, thinking of this as being free on the simplices not contained in $A$, is the usual boundary operator, except you send any boundary face contained in $A$ to zero.

2) The reason that $C_*(X,A)$ is a free abelian group on those generators is very general. If you have a free abelian group with a specified basis (for instance, $C_*(X)$), and you have a subgroup spanned by a subset of that basis ($C_*(A)$, spanned by simplices contained in $A$), then the quotient is free on the remaining basis elements. This is just a definition chase.

3) The correct statement is that the sequence $C_*(A) \to C_*(X) \to C_*(X,A)$ does not admit a splitting *as chain complexes*, that is, there is no section $C_*(X,A) \to C_*(X)$ which preserves the boundary operator. The obvious section described in (1) does not preserve the boundary operator.

4) It seems claimed in the other answer that for any exact sequence $$0 \to A \to B \to C \to 0$$ with $A,B$ free abelian, this sequence splits. That is false. In fact there is such a short exact sequence for any abelian group $C$ whatsoever. It should be easy to see how to construct one with $C = \Bbb Z/n$.

Comment: The key point is that the sequence does not split in maps of chain complexes, it only splits as graded abelian groups, which is not enough to split on homology.

Comment: It is contained in the above answer (among other things). I just wanted to highlight the key point.